# int 21 h is not working with AH=0Eh

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I want to change the default drive to drive D: but it doesn't work, on screen shows up the same drive. Does anyone know why? What did I do wrong?

```
assume cs:code,ds:data
data segment
data ends
code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov cl,3

mov ah,0eh
mov dl,cl
int 21h


mov ah,19h
int 21h

mov bl,al


mov ah,02h
mov dl,bl
int 21h

mov ax,4C00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: After `mov bl,al` I'd do `add bl, 'A'` to convert it to a displayable drive letter. The code should work. Do you have a Drive D on your system to change to? The code worked here under DOSBOX - it did change the drive letter, and you could see the change at the DOS prompt to. Are you using EMU8086?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm using DOSBOX 0.74 and it just doesn't want to change the default disk. It changes the disk only if I want to set the disk to A: or B:  for other values in dl which are not 0 or 1 doesn't work

Comment: It worked here but I had a drive D mounted. If you are at a command prompt what happens if you type `D:` . Does it change the drive?

Comment: @MichaelPetch   No. It says that D: does not exist. I initially mounted E: and after I run this program it outputs E instead of D.

Comment: If you can't change to drive D: from the command line you can't change to D: from a program (because it doesn't exist). You can only change to drive letters that are present.

Comment: @MichaelPetch so, if I want to change to D: my E: drive I should mount it  too after I mounted E:  right?

Comment: You have to mount something as D: .That is in the DOSBox config or you can use the mount command.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very very much! It worked! Thanks a lot!